# Why does my Eevee renders freeze at 98%?

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine

I have here a strange situation today. On Blender 2.81 and 2.82, while trying to render a scene file, that I've been assembling for years, it strangely now keeps freezing at 98% and returns several **"TIFFReadDirectory:Warning, unknown field with tag 18246 (0x4746) encountered"**
...But I don't even have Tiff textures on the objects, they are all .png
...Some versions ago (from 2 months ago) render just fine, but from some point on, this error occurs.

Anyone knows what can be this related to? At least a clue?

It's surely not memory, I have a 12Gb Graphic Card (TitanX) and I can deactivate all collections (having just a few Mb of memory in use) and I still get the error.

Thank you very much for the attention!

Best regards,

Rogério

[image]

**Edit:** I've found the reason of the problem! It was some TIFF images loaded on a no longer existing object and the freezing at 98% was due it being render a 2nd ViewLayer that had all the objects turned on:
[image]
This view layer wasn't being used on the compositor and as such I wasn't seeing this render result in any place until now. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only reason for this warning is that Blender is trying to read a TIFF.

Objects are not the only things that might use TIFFs. You might check your skydome or environment texture. If you have BlenderGuru's Pro-lighting Skies, then it's probably loading TIFFs at some point. You may have some other addon that uses TIFF images.

If you can upload a copy of your .blend file, someone here might be able to help you track down what images are causing the problem.

Comment: Thank you very much for the fast reply! The .blend only has linked objects and materials from other files. I can, but It's a scene file that loads all the data from hundreds of other files. You would only see empties probably. As such, that means that the ghost TIFF may be coming with any of those... inclusively may be orphan data. Thanks once again, at least now I understand what the error report is! :) I'll report here as soon I find that TIFF.

Comment: Ok! I did had the TIFF images on some objects that no longer exist, but their data somehow was kept. Having removed all the TIFF images, that error report disappeared. The 98% render freeze still persists do, but this time doesn't report any error. Will need to investigate more.

Comment: I've found the reason of the freezing of the render. As it turned out it was just rendering a 2nd View Layer that had all the objects turned on :| Thus it would take forever to render that viewlayer that wasn't being used on the compositor. Thanks for everything Matt! :) I wouldn't have been able to solve this without your help!